# Ruby add / sum variable

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for an explanation as to why this works:

```
def somesum
  x = 0
  (1..10).each do |number|
    x += number
  end
  puts x
end
```

whereas this does not work (undefined method '+' for nil class):

```
def somesum
  (1..10).each do |number|
    x += number
  end
  puts x
end
```

neither does this:

```
def somesum
  (1..10).each do |number, x|
    x += number
  end
  puts x
end
```

Comment: Your code snippets are incomplete: they contain a `def` and a `do`, but only one `end`. It's unclear if `puts x` is within the loop or outside.

Comment: If `x = 0` is missing, what do you expect for `x += 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference why your first example works, is because you initialized x:

```
x = 0
```

whereas the last two example try to add 1 to nil in the first loop, which doesn't work, since nil has no method '+'.
Please consider, that your example is a bad implementation achieving the goal.
A better solution is to use the accumulator approach. For example [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
(1..10).inject(0){ |sum, number| sum += number }
```

or even better:

```
(1..10).inject(:+)
```

which accumulates implicitly.

[Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) works the same:

```
(1..10).reduce(:+)
```

For a better understanding, please go reading [Iterators: inject and reject](http://www.chrisrolle.com/blog/iterators-inject-and-reject)

Comment: Or `(1..10).sum` (the question was initially tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails-4])

Comment: Sorry. It is tagged with Ruby only. The examples are Ruby only and there seem to be no relation to Rails in any way.

Comment: Actually, OP tagged rails, and @YuHao removed the rails tag, which would've made `.sum` valid. Either way, good answer.

Comment: I thought `inject` and `reduce` are synonyms for the same method?

Comment: They are. Maybe the answer is somewhat misleading. I'll edit.

Comment: typo: you have `reject` instead of `reduce`

Comment: The first parameter in the block is actually the `sum` so semantically your code is incorrect. It should be `{ |sum, number|  #code }`. You can see for example here `(2..5).reduce(25){ |sum,number| sum } #=> 25` the initial sum. I think it's subtle but important. 
`

Comment: thnx for all your very useful comments! I was assuming ruby(magic) would initialize x as a (local) variable upon introducing it. Not so, as it appears. Furthermore, I'm using a similar piece of code within Ruby on Rails model and I'm certainly going to try the `inject` or `reduce` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the second and third examples `x` has no value. Remember that:

```
x += number
```

is a shortening for:

```
x = x + number
```

so you're doing:

```
x = nil + number
```

and nil has no `:+` method.